# Java - Thread with runnable not starting

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having some problems with a thread that doesn't want to start. I have three classes. A main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T1 t1 = new T1();
        T2 t2 = new T2();
    }
}
```

A class inheriting from `Thread`:

```
public class T1 extends Thread {
    public T1() {run();}
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("Thread 1");         
        }
    }
}
```

And a class implementing `Runnable`:

```
public class T2 implements Runnable {
    public T2() {new Thread(this).start();}
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("Thread 2");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I expect both the `t1` and `t2` objects to print their messages every second, but it's only `t1` that does so; `t2` doesn't print anything. But if I swap the order and instantiate `t2` before `t1`, then both of them start printing as expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: start a thread as you haven't done that in code

Comment: Haven't you at least wondered why you call `#run` in `T1` and `#start` in `T2` and researched for the differences? Why not?

Comment: Always amused (in a very sad way) when I see legitimate questions like this downvoted. Frosting on the cake are comments like the one posted by @Tom.

Comment: @Mark Want a tissue? If you like this question, then feel free to upvote it, but don't think you have any right to question the voting decisions of others. And if you don't like comments about missing research, then ... well ... it's not my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public T1() {run();}
```

You never started a thread; you just called `run()` directly, which runs forever in the original thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use the start() method to start the threads. So your main will look something like

```
    T1 t1 = new T1();
    T2 t2 = new T2();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

Get rid of the the constructors in your thread classes. They should not be starting the threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** `T1` and `T2` have not been started as threads.  Since you have directly invoked run() method instead of start() method, things are not working as expected.

Once t1  object is created, you are calling `run()` method in constructor, which in-turn calls `sleep()` in infinite `while` loop. Next statement to create t2 object has not been invoked at all.

**Fix:** Remove `run()` call in `constructors` of both `T1 and T2 classes` and call `start()` on these two threads.

In `T1` constructor, Change code from

```
 public T1() {run();}
```

to

```
public T1() {}
```

Same is the case with `T2()` constructor. Remove `run()` method  as explained above.

Change main method from

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    T1 t1 = new T1();
    T2 t2 = new T2();
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    T1 t1 = new T1();
    t1.start();
    T2 t2 = new T2();
    t2.start();
}
```

Read oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) on how to start thread. run() method should be invoked by java virtual machine and not by code. You just have to call `start()` method, which in-turn calls `run()` method

```
public void start()
```

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the **Java Virtual Machine** calls the run method of this thread.